# JQuery .toggle() is not working on IE9 with select options

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, toggle

I have a slight problem. I have two dependent dropdown lists. If u select sth on first  then on second you should see filtered options. Everything is working well on FF but when I try it on IE9 then toggle stops working. I have all options visible.
My codes:

```
HH1:
<select name="color">
    <option value="1">blue</option>
  <option value="2">red</option>
</select>

HH2:
<select name="size">
  <option value="0" data-shown="0" data-link="">Please select</option>  
  <option value="1" data-shown="1" data-link="link1">L</option>
  <option value="2" data-shown="1" data-link="link2">M</option>
  <option value="3" data-shown="2" data-link="link3">XL</option>
  <option value="23" data-shown="2" data-link="link4">XM</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$('select[name="color"]').change(function () {
    var number = parseInt($('option:selected', this).attr('value'));
    $('select[name="size"] option').each(function(){       
        if (parseInt($(this).attr('data-shown')) != 0){              
            $(this).toggle(false);           
            $(this).toggle(parseInt($(this).attr('data-shown')) == number);
        }else {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
        }});
}).trigger('change');
```

If you have some solution please help.
..... I wonder if I should put it in document ready script or sth.

my example: http://jsfiddle.net/KD7Q5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShankarSangoli's answer is a good one.  I will add that if you want the options to disappear, you can keep a hidden `select` and copy the options out of it and into the visible one.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XjShS/

In this example, I have a `select` named `hsize` (hidden size... don't choose lousy names like I do).  That has all of the options.  When the `change` handler triggers, it clears the options in the `size` select, and then adds in the appropriate ones from `hsize`.

Answer (score 0):

IE do not support hiding an option element. If disabling will work for you then I would suggest you to do that.

Working demo with disabling option - http://jsfiddle.net/KD7Q5/3/

Comment: You didn't seem to save your changes... The fiddle is the same as the original.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. It is some solution, but i think it will not satisfy my customer.... I'm guessing that I should make some array with options and add and remove some depending on selection on first list. Is there possibility to dynamically add and remove options from select  ?

Comment: @ResoR: If you look at my answer, that is what it does.

Comment: Yes I have noticed ... Thanks again. One question more. Will this my/yours code work in IE7 (I mean: attributes data-* in option tag)

Comment: I just checked that it works in Compatibility mode IE7 in IE9 browser. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with dynamically repopulating the `size` element every time a choice is made for the `color` element. Its a cross-browser solution for your "problem" and you won't have to deal with hiding options.